# SQL Transact - Trigger on an INSERT into a specific table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to write a SQL Transact trigger that execute a simple task if an `INSERT` is called but only if the `INSERT` modify the table `t` (so if `INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (...)`.

I'm using `if (UPDATE[col])` into a trigger for performing a task but obliviously, it isn't calls when the row is created and I need to manage this case too.

I've seen `EVENT_DATE` and `AFTER INSERT` but I don't know how to perform it only if `INSERT` operates into a specific table `t`.

Can I have an example how to do this?

This is a pseudo-code:

```
IF (new row is insert on T) OR (T.c is updated)
{
 My task
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189799.aspx

```
-- SQL Server Syntax 
Trigger on an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement to a table or view (DML Trigger)

CREATE TRIGGER [ schema_name . ]trigger_name 
ON { table | view } 
[ WITH <dml_trigger_option> [ ,...n ] ]
{ FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } 
{ [ INSERT ] [ , ] [ UPDATE ] [ , ] [ DELETE ] } 
[ WITH APPEND ]
[ NOT FOR REPLICATION ] 
AS { sql_statement  [ ; ] [ ,...n ] | EXTERNAL NAME <method specifier [ ; ] > }
```

so you need something like

```
create trigger mytrigger 
on mytable
for insert, update
as 
   // stuff to do
```

or if you want to write update and insert seperately

```
create trigger mytrigger_update
on mytable
for update
as 
   // stuff to do for update


create trigger mytrigger_insert
on mytable
for insert
as 
   // stuff to do for insert
```

Comment: Perfect, I hadn't saw the "ON" clausole.  Thank you

Comment: and make sure your action staement assumes multiple records inteh insert or update. Never write a SQL server trigger qwwith teh assumption only one record wil be in the batch. Test it will a multiple record insert and a multipe record update as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ schema_name. ]trigger_name
ON T
AFTER INSERT
AS {
your statement here
}
```

This statement creates a triger with the name trigger_name on Table T that will fire after an insert on this Table

Comment: given your table name is T,  schema name is optional

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer.